# Import data from any excel file to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I want to import any Excel file which I will browse and want to show it in ASP.Net `GridView` Server Controls.

But I think my `connectionstring` is giving me problem.

When I run, it gives "`data source name not found and no default driver specified`".

I am using `ODBC data source` provider which is `Microsoft Excel driver`.

Here is the connection string which I wrote. "path" is the path which I will extract when the file is uploaded.

```
connString ="Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver(*.xls,*xlsx,*.xlsm,*.xlsb)}; Dbq=";
connString = connString + path +";Dsn=dsn;defaultdir=D:\\Users\\avantika.borikar;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2;" ;
```

Comment: I use this connstring and it works fine: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='<FULL PATH OF THE FILE>';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';

Comment: No I cant use OleDb,I have to use ODBC.

Comment: I am not able to figure out what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

suppose you have excel sheet with two columns "Name" and "Location"
open excel sheet select both the columns and assign a name .. suppose "mylist"

**How to Assign Name**

1-open excel and select both the columns including header (Name and Location)

2-right click go to "Define names"

3-assign Name "mylist"

create dsn say "mydsn"

use following code

it will work

```
protected void Page_load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection conn=new OdbcConnection("DSN=mydsn");
OdbcDataAdapter ad=new OdbcDataAdapter("select * from mylist",conn);
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
ad.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource=ds;
GridView1.DataBind();

}
```